# Lucene Reverse Phrase Search

Tags: search, lucene, reverse

If I want to search for Keyword "Error Message" , Can lucene be able to lend me results matching "Error Message" and "Message Error".  Currenlty i am getting results matching "Error Message" Only. I am using Standard Analyser and Query Parser for searching a Keyword.

Comment: Please do click a tick to choose an answer, if one of them was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `PhraseQuery` with slop > 0. From the [javadoc](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/PhraseQuery.html):

> Sets the number of other words permitted between words in query
>   phrase. If zero, then this is an exact phrase search. For larger
>   values this works like a WITHIN or NEAR operator. The slop is in fact
>   an edit-distance, where the units correspond to moves of terms in the
>   query phrase out of position. For example, to switch the order of two
>   words requires two moves (the first move places the words atop one
>   another), so to permit re-orderings of phrases, the slop must be at
>   least two.
>
> More exact matches are scored higher than sloppier matches, thus
>   search results are sorted by exactness.
>
> The slop is zero by default, requiring exact matches.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything that will do quite that, other than doing it as a search for "Error Message" OR "Message Error".

But if you search for

```
Title:(Error AND Message)
```

then you'll get everything where the title matches "Error" and "Message".

**One key point, though**: if you're programmatically constructing a Lucene query, you really shouldn't be using `QueryParser`. You should be using a `QueryBuilder` to construct it structurally. `QueryParser` is only for human-generated queries that a user might type into your application.