# Lucene Analyzer query and Search Results Relevance Score

Tags: java, search, lucene, analyzer

first of all, sorry for my bad English!

i am new to Lucene Library(Since last Wednesday) and im trying to understand how to get best relevance level of matching documents based on the terms found.

**i use Lucene 4.10.0  (no Solr)**

I'm able to index/search english/arabic text as well as supporting hit highlighting for these texts.

now i have a Problem with the relevance of search results.

if i search for "Mohammad Omar" in three docs:

```
doc1.add(new TextField("contents", "xyz abc, 123 Mohammad Abu Omar 123", Field.Store.YES));
indexWriter.addDocument(config.build(taxoWriter, doc1));

doc2 = new Document();
doc2.add(new TextField("contents", "xyz abc, 123 Omar bin Mohammad 123", Field.Store.YES));
indexWriter.addDocument(config.build(taxoWriter, doc2));

doc3 = new Document();
doc3.add(new TextField("contents", "xyz abc, 123 Abu Mohammad Omar 123", Field.Store.YES));
indexWriter.addDocument(config.build(taxoWriter, doc3));
...etc
```

**i get same Score for these 3 docs.**

it looks like Lucene ignores the Words Order and just scoring on the Matches Count.

**i expect the following as best Results:**

***doc3 THEN doc1 THEN doc2***

**but i get:**

***doc1 THEN doc2 THEN doc3 (ALL HAVE SAME SCORE)***

for searching in lowercase and in substrings i use an extended Analyzer like this:

```
   @Override
   protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
     Tokenizer source = new WhitespaceTokenizer(reader);
     TokenStream filter = new LowerCaseFilter(source);   
     filter = new WordDelimiterFilter(filter,Integer.MAX_VALUE,null);
     return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);
   }
```

any idea how to perform it?

from here: http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Boosting_a_Term

i see that Boosting Query Terms AND/OR using RegEx could be an Option, but this means, i have to handle User inputs manually. isn't there an "out of box" Solution(like a function, Filter or Analyzer)?

many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How does your `"Mohammad Omar"` query look like in terms of code? If you need just this exact phrase, feed this string into a `PhraseQuery` or if you use `QueryParser`, wrap this phrase into quotes to produce `PhraseQuery`.

If you need both this phrase as well as documents containing both terms separately in the search results, you could include `"Mohammad Omar"` both as a phrase (as specified above) and as separate terms, something like this: `some_field:"Mohammad Omar" some_field:Mohammad some_field:Omar`. You can also add boosting for the phrase element so that phrase results rank higher.

Comment: thanks for your repley, i use queryParser, and i need results containing exact phrase + all subphrases (the order of terms is very important). but if the requested phrase is long, lets say 30 words, then do i have to manually build all subpgrases and boosting them too? isn't there an out of box class to perform this?

Comment: For out of the box solution you could use slop parameter with `PhraseQuery` although it works a little bit different. Read my answer for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25421915/7345) for more details. Regarding my original proposal - it's not like you will have to do rewriting by hand every time ;-)